# What is the vampires' take on demons?

Tags: lore, world-of-darkness

In medieval times as far as I remember demons were seen as enemies (earthbound mostly). In modern nights does that still hold true? Are they seen as enemies to be hunted on sight still or not?

And what about elder vampires, does the stance typically change for them?

Comment: Which Demon splat book is this using? Just for clarity as the versions of these games get confusing

Comment: @AncientSwordRage mostly revised (though where they exist also v20)

Comment: Is revised before or after GMC?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage its world of darkness. GMC  I guess is god machine chronicles, thus nwod or chronicles of darkness.   the wold of darkness I'm talking about is OWOD or old world of darkness how it was called for some time.

Answer (score 12):

In modern nights, a recently embraced vampire is likely to consider the existence of Demons pretty much the same way you would; incredulity, some fear, and some curiosity. If the vampire was religious, there might be a pretty violent reaction.

Most vampires learn about the existence of vampires through the Embrace, most vampires never learn about Demons.

Elder vampires, on the other hand, are likely to react more negatively; the further back in time you go, the more likely the vampire is to have had some sort of contact with or at least heard about the [Baali](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Baali), who can be considered a blend of vampire and demon, (possibly?) born from a rather disturbing collaboration between the Antedeluvian [Saulot](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Saulot) and the Earthbound Demon [Baal](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Baal).

Answer (score 6):

### Baali

The Baali are asshole vampires that worship demons and the whole reason behind the love of Assamites for kindred-blood - they cursed the Assamites after the sons of Haqim beat them almost out of existence for being demon worshippers **twice**. They have demonology rites... and besides the Tremere, Assamites, and Salubrii are the only ones that have a clue that demons actually exist. They are hated and despised by **all** other vampires, being one is more of an automatic death sentence than having a third eye!

### Salubrii

They are the *other* kids of Saulot. They and the Assamites beat the Baali nearly out of existence. And they are the exact opposite of Baali: they **hate** Demons. And since they are just about a handful that holds the entire memory of their clan... believe me, the half dozen of them have some 6 millennia of hatred for them.

### Assamites

The Children of Haqim have written it on their flag that they will exterminate Demons. They hate Baali and Demons with more passion than they hate Tremere. That is, those that do know about them. Many youngsters don't know, but the elders... oh boy, they know and **hate** them.

### Tremere

They are children of Saulot and Mages... they **know** and they have strict rules that grant you a sunbath if you so much as *try* to dabble in demonology. Call it the heritage of their leader actually being Saulot, or them being formerly a member of the Order of Hermes that had handed Demon-research even before they were vampires...

### Everybody else

If they know that Demons exist, they **hate** them. Because those that do know they exist, know that they are the reason behind the [Baali Wars](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Baali_Wars) and the fall of the first cities... which might actually be a rather short list: the clans up above, Backet, and possibly some dozen handful individuals globally know specifics.

However, hatred of demons in general is heavily enforced: In every clan but the Baali and the Setites - and that includes the Sabbat - dabbling in [Infernalism](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Infernalism_(WOD)) is a death sentence, even if the people have no clue what an *earthbound* or proper *Demon* is.

The Demon hunters of the Kindred are the [Sabbat Inquisition](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Sabbat_Inquisition) and [Camarilla Josians](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Josians), both actively hunting down Baali and Infernalists, in addition to the Assamites & remaining Salubrii.